# Why are the parametric equations of a torus functions of the angles(u, v) only?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

I was assigned to find the line element ($ds^2$) of a torus. In order to do so, the first step is to take the partial derivates of the following parametrization:

$x(u, v) = (c + a\cos(v))\cos(u)$

$y(u, v)=(c+acos(v))sin(u)$

$z(u, v)=asin(v)$

What caught my attention is that we only consider the two angular variables ($u$, $v$) and not $a$ and $c$ unlike something like a cylinder ($\rho$,$\theta$,$z$) or a sphere ($r$,$\theta$,$\phi$) where three variables are considered.

So why is the parametrization of a torus a function of two variables and not three($a$, $u$, $v$) ($c$, $u$, $v$) or four ($a$, $c$, $u$, $v$)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, Well, a sphere is just $\rho = \text{const}$, so that's really minimal. I guess one way to think about it would be to consider a similar parametrization of a circle of radius $c$ and center $(a,b)$ in the plane: $x=a+c\cos\theta, y=b+c\sin\theta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for a cylinder, you only use two of your three cylindrical coordinates, namely $(\theta,z)$. For a sphere, you only use two of your three spherical coordinates, namely $(\theta,\phi)$. In both cases, the "radius" coordinate is constant. In general, to call an object a surface, you should have a parametrization (with some properties) by *two* independent variables.

You can have three, four, or — indeed — arbitrarily many *dependent* variables. For example, here's a parametrization of a torus in $4$-space:
$$(x,y,z,w) = (\cos u,\sin u, \cos v, \sin v).$$

Comment: So the parametrization implies only points on the _surface_ of the torus?
Would finding a point within the torus require more variables?

Comment: Absolutely correct. Similarly, "cylinder" and "sphere" refer (in higher mathematics) just to the surfaces. We normally say *solid cylinder* or *ball* if we include the interiors.